# trying to use which function to pull data from a raster if condition satisfied in other raster

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have two rasters that are of same size and contains data from the same location, but different types of data (one raster has slope data and the other has aspect data). I want to be able to look at slope data for one aspect at a time, so I was trying to create a setup (maybe an if/else statement?) where I said "if (aspect condition) was satisfied in one raster, the slope data would get pulled from that same pixel in the other raster.

```
#I have a slope and an aspect raster that i pulled
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

aspect <- raster("geotiff name here")
slope <- raster("geotiff name here") 

#Looking at the north aspect (between 0-22.5 degrees or 337.5-360 degrees)

#First I am setting the pixels in the aspect raster that correspond to north
#equal to 1, and the values that don't = 0  
aspect[aspect >= 0 & aspect <= 22.5] <- 1
aspect[aspect >= 337.5 & aspect <= 360] <- 1
aspect[aspect > 22.5 & aspect < 337.5] <- 0

#Here i am saving the indices of the raster that face north to a new one
north <- which(aspect == 1, cells = true)
```

Then I want to only read the data from the pixels of the slope raster that got assigned a TRUE value from the aspect raster, but this is where I've gotten stumped! I've started using R very recently so there is probably an easy way to do this I'm missing, and any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Done! Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always include example data (see the help files for inspiration, here from `?raster::terrain`)

```
library(raster)
x <- getData('alt', country='CHE')
aspect <- terrain(x, 'aspect', unit='degrees')
slope <- terrain(x, 'slope', unit='degrees')
```

This is a better way to reclassify:

```
m <- matrix(c(0,22.5,1,22.5,337.50,0,337.5,360,1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
aspectcls <- reclassify(aspect, m)
```

Get the slope data where aspectcls != 0

```
nslope <- mask(slope, aspectcls, maskvalue=0)
```

Get the values

```
v <- values(nslope)   
boxplot(v)
```

You could also do

```
crosstab(aspectcls, slope)
```

I would not recommend the path you took, but if you took it, you could do

```
cells <- Which(aspectcls, cells=T)
vv <- slope[cells]
boxplot(vv)
```

Comment: This worked! I adjusted how I plotted the data at the end, but everything else was the same. Thank you for teaching me about masking, very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert 1 to TRUE, as R does this automatically. Try this code:

```
#create a data frame
data <- data.frame(aspect=aspect, slope=slope)

#create a 'north' column and populate with 1
data$north <- 1

#those that don't meet the north criteria are converted to 0
data$north[data$aspect > 22.5 & data$aspect < 337.5] <- 0

#report the 'slope' values where north=1
data$slope[data$north == 1]
```

Comment: I tried this, but the data.frame function doesn't like that the aspect and slope are rasters. I know I can convert a raster to a data frame with as.data.frame, but I'm not quite sure how to convert 2 rasters into 1 data frame.

Comment: convert them separately and then use `cbind()`